# How to localize C++ app (win and mac) with common solution?

Tags: macos, localization, cross-platform

I have a cross platform app (Win and Mac) using C++. I want this app to be localized for both platforms to support few languages like German, French, etc., I am looking for a common approach to support for both platforms otherwise I have to go with platform specific localization. That will double the work.

Platform specific:

- Use Localizable.strings file for Mac
- User .xml file keeping it in resources for Win

I am looking for a common solution to support both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the related localization files into a const list of key-value tables on startup where each list would correspond to a language and each table in the list would contain localized strings for the specific language. Then reference the strings with keys from your code.